# How can I render component as data attribute in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

For example I have a template and some other `<my-component>`:

```
template: '<i data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-content="**Here I need render another  component in loop**"></i>'
```

This

```
 :data-content="<my-component v-for... ></my-component>"
```

doesn't work. Perhaps there is a method to  render my-component in another  place ? In computed area... or in methods ?

So, how can I render component in html data-*attributes  ?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the reason to have HTML inside data attribute? If you really need it, try to insert plain html string, not as a component. But it looks super invalid

Comment: @Anarion The reason is simple - Bootstrap Popover  :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert your component to be functional. Read [Introduction to Vue.js Render Functions](https://alligator.io/vuejs/introduction-render-functions/) and [Render Functional Components in Vue.js](https://alligator.io/vuejs/render-functional-components/)

Comment: Wich  exactly component should I to convert ? Do I have to remove <my-component>  and move it's functionality to the render function in my parent component ?

Comment: You should convert the component which you want to put inside the `data-content` attribute. The new functional component will be returning a DOM-fragment so you can easily get its `innerHTML`.

Comment: Sorry for the my arrogance, but can You illustrate it, very briefly, I can not understand some things  and my English does not allow me a more specific question. Thank You.

Comment: Hm, it seems that it would be simpler for you to avoid mixing Vue and jQuery stuff. If you insist on doing so perhaps you can have `<my-component ref="my">` somewhere inside your parent with `v-show="false"` and then inside the `mounted()` handler get the `this.$refs.my.innerHTML` and provide it to the `data-content` attribute of your popover. But this is too hacky - you'd be better stick with pure Vue-compatible components.